# An example of world map using dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

It would be great help if anyone can share an example of world map mapping using dimple.js.
I am trying to build a world map with data for e.g. say 7 countries.

For e.g.`{"USA": 30, "JAPAN": 40}`

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Dimple doesn't currently do maps, you could try Leaflet.

Comment: Does it make sense when I use dimplejs to draw an interactive map in d3? I'm a newbie in both.